# Clarification on C# Threading Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am using the C# threading tasks instruction from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-task).

They state at the end:

> The Result property blocks the calling thread until the task finishes.

Am I right in thinking this is just creating a thread for a function, but still holding up the main thread, and the progression of the calling function, as if it was running through a standard function call?

As a 2nd question, following on from my possibly incorrect first assumption, if I modified the code in the example to:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Return a value type with a lambda expression
        Task<int> task1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => 1);            

        // Return a named reference type with a multi-line statement lambda.
        Task<Test> task2 = Task<Test>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string s = ".NET";
            double d = 4.0;
            return new Test { Name = s, Number = d };
        });

        int i = task1.Result;
        Test test = task2.Result;    
    }
}
```

Would it create and run both threads simultaneously, running through the functions before returning the tasks? Or will it progress through the threads one a time as I assumed originally?

Comment: You're right, the Microsoft example will essentially call those functions synchronously. For your example, as you're invoking `StartNew`, they'll run at the same time. Once both are spawned, the main thread will wait for the first to terminate, then for the second to terminate, and collect their results in that order.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect, you should add that as an answer though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the Microsoft example will essentially call those functions synchronously:

```
...
Task<int> task1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => 1);
int i = task1.Result;

Task<Test> task2 = Task<Test>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    string s = ".NET";
    double d = 4.0;
    return new Test { Name = s, Number = d };
});
Test test = task2.Result;
...
```

`task1` will be started in a new thread, then the current thread will block until it returns its result. Then `task2` will start in a a new thread...

For your example, they'll run at the same time. `task1` is spawned, then `task2`, then the main thread waits for `task1`'s result and then for `task2`'s result.